# How to repeat string in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, repeat

I want to repeat `len(non_current_assets)` times a string in an array. So I tried:

```
["",  "totalAssets", "total_non_current_assets" * len(non_current_assets), "totalAssets"]
```

But it returns:

```
['',
 'totalAssets',
 'total_non_current_assetstotal_non_current_assetstotal_non_current_assetstotal_non_current_assetstotal_non_current_assets',
 'totalAssets']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your `str` inside `list`, multiply, then unpack (using `*` operator) that is:

```
non_current_assets = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  # so len(non_current_assets) == 5, might be anything as long as supports len
lst = ["",  "totalAssets", *["total_non_current_assets"] * len(non_current_assets), "totalAssets"]
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['', 'totalAssets', 'total_non_current_assets', 'total_non_current_assets', 'total_non_current_assets', 'total_non_current_assets', 'total_non_current_assets', 'totalAssets']
```

*(tested in Python 3.7)*

Comment: Works for me, thanks. I will let the question open for a while and will accept it if no better answer pops in

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
string_to_be_repeated = ["total_non_current_assets"]
needed_list = string_to_be_repeated * 3
list_to_appended = ["","totalAssets"]
list_to_appended.extend(needed_list)
print(list_to_appended)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a loop:

```
    for x in range(len(non_current_assets)):
       YOUR_ARRAY.append(”total_non_current_assets“)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) together with the unpacking operator `*`:

```
import itertools as it

["",  "totalAssets",
 *it.repeat("total_non_current_assets", len(non_current_assets)),
 "totalAssets"]
```

It makes the intent pretty clear and saves the creation of a temporary list (hence better performance).

```
In [1]: import itertools as it                                                                

In [2]: %timeit [0, 1, *[3]*1000, 4, 5]                                                       
6.51 µs ± 8.57 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit [0, 1, *it.repeat(3, 1000), 4, 5]                                             
4.94 µs ± 73.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```